# Hiding Specific Fields for Specific Language in Content Editor

Tags: content-editor

We need some specific customization to hide a specific field for a specific language. like hiding Title field for English language but not for Spanish etc. Please suggest a any way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override `CanShowField` method of `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields` class so that it returns `false` for specific fields when Content Language is `English`.

Here is you can create class something like follows. You can add additional criteria like checking for particular template.

```
public class GetFields : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields
{
    protected override bool CanShowField(Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field, TemplateField templateField)
    {
        if (field.Name == "Title" && field.Language == Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("es-Es"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.CanShowField(field, templateField);
    }   
}
```

After that you should apply patch to include your custom class.

```
<getContentEditorFields>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields, Sitecore.Client">
        <patch:attribute name="type">YourClass, YourAssembly</patch:attribute>
    </processor>
</getContentEditorFields>
```

Answer (score -2):

There are some blogs available for the same customization as below:

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/11/04/choose-template-fields-to-display-in-the-sitecore-content-editor/

https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/hiding-content-editor-fields-depending-on-selected-values/

http://andyuzick.arke.com/2013/07/Hiding-fields-in-the-Content-Editor.html

http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/hide-fields-on-specific-sitecore-items/

Also check the below marketplace module as well:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Hide_Field_Template_Extension.aspx